# Why phpseclibsftp returns "The directory '%s' does not exist and could not be created (%s)."?

Tags: php, sftp, phpseclib

When calling this

```
$fileSystem = $this->filesystemMap->get(IMReporter::FILE_SYSTEM_SFTP_NAME);
$fileSystem->write($filename, file_get_contents($tempFile));
```

I get The directory '/home/darius/Desktop/veracitytest' does not exist and could not be created ().

I have created the directory and set permissions to 777 manually. When debugging I see it calls

```
protected function ensureDirectoryExists($directory, $create)
{
    $pwd = $this->sftp->pwd();
    if ($this->sftp->chdir($directory)) {
        $this->sftp->chdir($pwd);
    } elseif ($create) {
        if (!$this->sftp->mkdir($directory, 0777, true)) {
            throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('The directory \'%s\' does not exist and could not be created (%s).', $this->directory, $this->sftp->getLastSFTPError()));
        }
    } else {
        throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('The directory \'%s\' does not exist.', $this->directory));
    }
}
```

and it calls !$this->sftp->mkdir($directory, 0777, true)

In mkdir there is such code

```
if (!($this->bitmap & SSH2::MASK_LOGIN)) {
    return false;
}
```

which returns false and so I get the error.

$this->bitmap is 7. I dont get what it is trying to do here. In the lib there is such comment:

```
 /**
     * Execution Bitmap
     *
     * The bits that are set represent functions that have been called already.  This is used to determine
     * if a requisite function has been successfully executed.  If not, an error should be thrown.
     *
     * @var int
     * @access private
     */
var $bitmap = 0;
```

So far I did no find where it even sets it to 7.

Using https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer - I get this message when I have entered wrong password.

Comment: Yup - that's exactly it - because the login failed `$this->bitmap` is never OR'd with `SSH2::MASK_LOGIN` so `if (!($this->bitmap & SSH2::MASK_LOGIN)) {` returns false and thus the `\RuntimeException` exception is thrown.